# How can I fix DAX XIRR calculation for projects with different investment start dates?

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I am managing an enterprise strategy that is moving people and real estate across multiple geographies.  The strategy is comprised of a large number of projects that can be considered independent of each other and taken together sum up to the strategy.  Items we are capturing include existing labor cost & real estate costs, and we are comparing that to the labor, real estate, and investment cost of the moves.  Each of these items is captured in separate fact tables and they are all linked via a dimension table.

I was able to define a variable that uses UNION and SELECTCOLUMNS to create a consolidated table to calculate the NPV and that worked great.  When I used the same approach to calculate the XIRR it works for most projects, but gives an error for ones that have an investment date greater than year one.  I have tried to apply CALCULATE with a FILTER where Date is greater than or equal to the First Investment Date for that project, but it didn't work.

```
IRR:=VAR CashFlowTable =  
    UNION (  
        SELECTCOLUMNS (  
            LaborComponent,  
            "Date", LaborComponent[Date],  
            "Values", LaborComponent[Base vs Deploy],  
            "Index", LaborComponent[Index]  
        ),  
        SELECTCOLUMNS (  
            RealEstateCosts,  
            "Date", RealEstateCosts[Date],  
            "Values", RealEstateCosts[Base vs Deploy],  
            "Index", RealEstateCosts[Index]  
        ),  
        SELECTCOLUMNS (  
            HRCosts,  
            "Date", HRCosts[Date],  
            "Values", HRCosts[Base vs Deploy],  
            "Index", HRCosts[Index]  
        )  
    )  
RETURN  
    IFERROR (  
        CALCULATE (  
            XIRR ( CashFlowTable, [Values], [Date] ),  
            FILTER(CashFlowTable, [Date] >= [First Investment Date] )),  
        BLANK ()  
    )
```

where

```
First Investment Date :=
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), [Total Investment] < 0 )
)
```

and

```
Total Investment := SUM ( HRCosts[Value] )
```

Comment: What's the DAX formula for `[First Investment Date]`?

Comment: The investment is represented as a negative, the formula is:   'First Investment Date:=CALCULATE (
        MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), [Total Investment] < 0 )
    )'

Comment: The formula for the Total Investment measure is simply, 'Total Investment:=SUM(HRCosts[Value])'

Comment: I'd first try declaring `[First Investment Date]` as `VAR` before using it inside the `FILTER`. It's easier to debug that way even if it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Declaring the First Investment Date as VAR appears to have fixed the issue.  What is the reason it works when declaring VAR and not from the measure?

Answer (score 0):

A measure is calculated within the filter context you put it in, so I recommend declaring `[First Investment Date]` as a `VAR` before using it inside the `FILTER`.

When you calculate `[First Investment Date]` as a `VAR` first, it's evaluated within the filter context of the measure. When you calculate `[First Investment Date]` inside of the `FILTER`, it's evaluated within the row context of the table being filtered. It's not clear to me what exactly is the difference between these contexts in your particular case, but it's much simpler to understand and debug if you pre-calculate the measure.

Pre-calculating `[First Investment Date]` as a `VAR` should also be more efficient since you only have to calculate it once, rather than for each row of `CashFlowTable`.